# How to provoke a client certificate request usning Schannel

Tags: authentication, ssl, server, schannel

I am writing TLS server side code using schannel and need to require the client to mutually authenticate itself.  I know this is done by sending a client certificate request at the end of the server hello.  I see how to do it in openssl but I can not find how to do it with schannel.

EDIT.

The short answer is to use ASC_RET_MUTUAL_AUTH.

Answer (score 0):

The slightly longer answer is to use ASC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH with AcceptSecurityContext, and then the client must respond to InitializeSecurityContext returning SEC_I_INCOMPLETE_CREDENTIALS.